# Why does `viewWillAppear` set `animated` to true even when presenting with `present(_, animated: false, _)`?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

So I present some view controller (loaded from xib)

```
let popup = PopupViewController()
popup.configure(withDataSource: dataSource)
vc.present(popup, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

As you can see, I ask to present it with no animation. However, the `animated` flag in `viewWill\DidAppear` in the presented view controller is set to `true`

[image]

Am I getting something wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @emil nope I didn't

Answer (score 0):

presenting viewcontroller is vc transition from one vc to another and viewWillAppear:animated is view animation which will be shown.

---

As per Apple doc:

If a view controller is presented by a view controller inside of a popover, this method is not invoked on the presenting view controller after the presented controller is dismissed.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear)

Comment: Don't see how is it relevant. It is being called, only the "animation" parameter behaves strangely.